# Get data from a form with iframe inside

Tags: html, servlets, iframe

i have one noob question!

In my page, i have one form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="BuscarDadosArvore">

     <iframe name="conteudo" 
             id="conteudo" 
             width="100%" 
             frameborder="0" 
             scrolling="auto" 
             height="100%" 
             src="buscaPorFamilia.jsp">
     </iframe>

     <input type="submit" value="Search!"/>

</form>
```

the iFrame changes the src via javascript when a user press one Button radio...

In all pages that i put in ifram src have one input type text that i want to recovery in servlet "BuscarDadosArvore"!

But the request.getParameter() doesn't work...

how can i proceed?
thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: "get" the data - where? On the server after submit, or on the page using JavaScript?

Comment: Why don't you just use a server side include by `<jsp:include>`? Why doing it the hard way with an `<iframe>` and a good load of JavaScript?

Comment: Diodeus, i want get the data in the Servlet

Comment: BalusC, i dont't know how do this, im noob, i'll search how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

An Iframe is essentially a window to another browser session.

The contents of the Iframe are not actually inside your page, therefore you cannot submit them as part of a form.

Look into including the contents of "buscaPorFamilia.jsp" inside the page that contains your form.

Comment: what i can do is add one form and one button submit inside buscaPorFamilia.jsp, but when i call the foward with requestDispatcher object inside the servlet, the page returns inside the iFrame, and i dont want to do this